# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property - when changing a global var from a reducer function

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror

I'm new to Javascript/React Native and I can't wrap my head around this error.

```
var path = []; // Global var

export const updatePathReducer = (
  state = path,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATEPATH":

      console.log("action.currentposition" + action.currentPosition.latitude); // The value that gets printed here is not null

      path.push(action.currentPosition); // <---- TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property 

      return path;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

[image]

From what I've learned I should be able to just change a global variable like this.
I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: There's no assignment on the line you indicated so I don't believe the error is actually originating there. Are you using typescript? Can you post the full error?

Comment: Hi @windowsill, I updated my question, this is all the information I have on the error. I'm using javascript. thanks

Comment: All I can tell you is that the error is not in the code you posted (I mean it's valid js after all, you can just paste it into console and it works), but rather is in redux or getGeolocation or higher.